# How to achieve secure TCP tunneling for my Java TCP application server?

Tags: java, tcp, tunneling

I have built a simple Java TCP application server running on ports 7777 and 8888.
Usually works fine, but the problem is sometimes the clients are connected via WiFi in public locations, in which these ports are blocked.

I have read that there is a method called 'TCP Tunneling' that enables to get all the incoming connection through a secured tunnel (port 443 I believe) and forward it to the server, enabling the connection to be established even in locations where ports 7777 and 8888 are blocked.

Searching on google I find many tools named 'java-tcp-tunnel' and such, but I'm still unsure how to implement this using this tool.

Any experience you can share with me will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 0 answers. Thanks guys ^^